# How to develop and test Cordova SQLite application in browser?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, browser

The only way that I found is PouchDB with different adapters for browser and device. But this way does't fit for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another way this using [Cordova-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage)
Just use different Database object for browser and device.

This is part of my code(ES6):

```
var runiOS = false;
var DB;

// Check browser or device

var onDeviceReady = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {    
    if (document.URL.match(/^https?:/i)) {
        console.log("Running in a browser...");
        resolve();
    } else {
        console.log("Running in an app...");
        runiOS = true;
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", resolve, false);
    }
});

// Run application
onDeviceReady.then(function() {
    //  Init WebSQL on browser or SQLite on device
    if (runiOS) {
        DB = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: 'my.db', location: 'default' }, function (db) {}, function (error) { console.log('Open database ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(error)); });          
        console.log('DB: SQLite');
    }
    else {
        DB = window.openDatabase('my', "0.1", "My list", 200000);    
        console.log('DB: WebSQL');
    }

    // ...

    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DemoTable (name, score)');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DemoTable VALUES (?,?)', ['Alice', 101]);
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DemoTable VALUES (?,?)', ['Betty', 202]);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log('Transaction ERROR: ' + error.message);
    }, function() {
        console.log('Populated database OK');
    });


    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT count(*) AS mycount FROM DemoTable', [], function(tx, rs) {
            console.log('Record count (expected to be 2): ' + rs.rows.item(0).mycount);
        }, function(tx, error) {
            console.log('SELECT error: ' + error.message);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This is only example of initialisation. Of course this code can't run. I will edit answer.